# How do I populate data in intercom custom attributes from segment?

Tags: segment, intercom

Segment offers page method call, where you can track the previous URL of a visitor prior to coming on your website.

I have this referrer URL with me, I want to push this referrer URL to intercom.

What I really want to do?

Whenever a user signs up on our software, I want to track his previous URL and make it available in intercom under his profile.

Also, the custom attribute created in intercom by me is not working since I don't know what code I should write in my intercom code snippet.

Please refer screenshots.

**Intercom**

[image: Intercom]

**Segment**
[image: Segment]

Answer (score 1):

Intercom by default saves the Referral URL of the user in a field called **`Referral url`**.

[image]

Else if you want to manually push referrer URL as a custom attribute you can send the parameter in the following way:

```
Intercom('boot', {
    app_id: '<<Your App ID>>',
    referrer:document.referrer, //custom attribute id which you have created in intercom
});
```

Comment: it's old but still helped me solving this, Intercom was not sending the referral url by default, it was always "Unknown" until I explicitly added "referrer:"